# Dead pixel count growing when the computer is shut off?

Tags: display, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

My computer is a Samsung Chromebook 3. I have a clump of dead and stuck pixels on the bottom left of my screen. I know that dead pixels can be nearly unfixable, but a few things i have tried have worked, including dead pixels test and fix. I let the program run for about an hour or two last night and the number of dead pixels shrunk dramatically and i was optimistic. I woke up this morning to the number of dead pixels was a little higher that it was the night before. I shut off my computer for about an hour earlier and the number of dead pixels grew a lot. Any pressure on the back of the computer, even when closed, makes it grow by a few pixels. It always has a white glow around it. Is there anything i can do to make the number of pixels stop growing? Even if the clump of pixels just shrunk a little bit I would be fine. I cannot pay for programs, for my screen to be fixed, or for a new computer. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Watch this reasonably professional video (EEV Blog) on replacing a small screen.  See if you can possibly do this. This would limit your cost to just the screen.   https://www.eevblog.com/2019/11/01/eevblog-1255-apple-ipad-5th-gen-screen-repair/

Comment: A photo might help - many people cannot tell the difference between dead, stuck & physical damage.